# postman req not responding any data even not responding error

Tags: express, post, routes, postman

Login routes:

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            mobileNo: req.body.mobileNo,
        });
        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json("You are not registerd");
        }
        const password = res.body.password;
        if (password === user.password) {
            return res.status(200).json("You are logged in");
        } else {
            return res.status(501).json("Naah! wrong pass");
        }
    } catch {
        (err) => {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        };
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js:

```js
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
```

import:

```js
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
```

My postman image, I am not getting any result.

[image: This is the image of postman I trying for 1 hour to fix this but not fixing I am not able to find any error as well]

Comment: Hey, Saurabh could you please share [Min Reproducible exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  There are a few unclear things in your question. Are you able to hit this endpoint? Is your awaited User retrieval call completed? Where is your request stuck?

Comment: no i am not able to hit the endpoint . when i click to send postman tries to send it but the request sending ... never goes off as you can see i the image

Comment: You can simply add console log statements at different places in your request pipeline and see where it is stuck. e.g. before try block, after user retrieval, and in the catch block. Though if you can use the debugger, it will be the best.

Comment: i applied console.log but returning noting  . do u find any error in my code if then let me know and one thing i was guessing could it happen because of slow internet

Comment: What do you see in logs? Is it hitting catch block? try to explicitly return the response in each case. e.g. Change "res.status(500).json(err);" to " return res.status(500).json(err);".

Comment: hey ! sorry for disturbing you but i got the actual problem and the problem is when i use my real credential to login i don't get anything but when i do not give the correct one i get the response .

Comment: Great! You must not store the password as plain text though. See a quick auth workflow blog [here](https://medium.com/@itsnewbietech/authentication-for-dummies-54975f9f0fbb).

Comment: no i haven't as i was testing first as u can see my code although if i would have done that i should have got like wrong password

Answer (score 0):

Your try-catch syntax is wrong, correct would be

```js
try {
  ...
} catch(err) {
  res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

With your syntax, when the catch block is reached, the `res.status(500).json(err)` statement is *not* executed, therefore the request never comes back.

Answer (score 0):

In your try block, there are 3 responses available. If the first condition in the if block is also executed with another one of the responses in the below if-else condition this problem may occur. Because at a time, sending 2 responses is impossible. Therefore, you should return that response and terminate.

```
if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json("You are not registered");
}
```